# When would you use recursive merge sort over iterative?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Is there ever a situation where you should use a recursive merge sort over an iterative merge sort? Originally I thought that iterative approaches to merge sort were typically faster although I could not prove that in my own implementations. But recursion makes a lot more calls on the stack which in turn makes it less memory efficient. What if I have an extremely large dataset that I want to sort? Wouldn't it be bad to use recursion then? Because doesn't excessively deep recursion eventually lead to a stack overflow? Why would you ever use recursive over iterative if it is slower and less memory efficient?

```
def merge_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr

    current_size = 1
    while current_size < len(arr):
        left = 0
        while left < len(arr)-1:
            mid = left + current_size - 1
            right = min((left + 2*current_size - 1), (len(arr)-1))
            merged_arr = merge(arr[left : mid + 1], arr[mid + 1 : right + 1])
            for i in range(left, right + 1):
                arr[i] = merged_arr[i - left]
            left = left + current_size*2
        current_size = current_size * 2
    return arr

def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    result += left[i:]
    result += right[j:]
    return result
```

```
def merge_sort_recursive(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    mid = len(arr) // 2
    left = arr[:mid]
    right = arr[mid:]
    left = merge_sort_recursive(left)
    right = merge_sort_recursive(right)
    return merge(left, right)

def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    result += left[i:]
    result += right[j:]
    return result
```

Comment: The levels of recursion are only log n, so not excessive even for large inputs.

Comment: If you want to speed up your recursive version, you should try to eliminate the unnecessary array copies.  Also, in `merge`, you know the size of the result in advance, so it's more efficient to allocate the entire array up front rather than growing it by appending.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, but even if I were to write a more efficient recursive merge sort algorithm they are typically not as fast or memory efficient as if I wrote it iteratively right? Or am I wrong in thinking that? If I am not wrong in thinking that then I am wondering what is the reason for choosing recursion? Just style?

Comment: Recursion is more expensive in python than C (for example) because of the cost of building a function object and local namespace for each call.

Comment: Recursion depth isn't an issue. Properly implemented, the recursive merge sort *always* uses O(log n) stack space. To sort 2^32 items, the recursion depth won't exceed 32 levels, which will likely be far less than one kilobyte of stack space.

Comment: Actually, recursion depth *is* an issue with this implementation because temporary `result` arrays are being allocated and returned with the recursion. What's shown here is a particularly poor implementation that requires O(n log n) extra space. It can be done with O(n) extra space.

Comment: @JimMischel It does take only O(n) extra space. Not all calls and their data exist at the same time, so memory gets reused all the time.

Comment: @KellyBundy Hmmmm. I need to wake up. Been too long since I played with this stuff and my recursive thinking is rusty. Merge sort typically takes O(n) extra space. You *can* write merge sort to take constant extra space, the ultimate being the in-place merge sort. Time complexity is still O(n log n), but the code is complicated and has an astonishingly high constant, making it not at all practical for real-world use.

Comment: @JimMischel Yeah I looked into constant space inplace stable merging before, it was fairly complicated (and part of the algorithm was in a paper I didn't have access to). This question's implementation isn't stable, so if we drop stability, I think it gets somewhat easier/faster, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** Hmm, after writing my own much simpler iterative one, I have to somewhat take back some of what I wrote...

```
def merge_sort_Kelly(arr):
    half = 1
    while half < len(arr):
        for mid in range(half, len(arr), 2*half):
            start = mid - half
            stop = mid + half
            arr[start:stop] = merge(arr[start:mid], arr[mid:stop])
        half *= 2
    return arr
```

Times for sorting three shuffled `list(range(2**17))` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVXbbuIwEH3nK/zWJAQK9GFXEXxBPwFFUUTsYpQ4kW22Yqt@O@vxOHYcUKXNC8nMmTO3YzPc9LkXb78Heb83lJGOyg9aqV7qpJYyLRbEPJyRlgprIPsD2aIVHkn1VQpiPAtrO12lpEJXiv@lxCCt8fPMWxq79p4wcLWUaROz8QaMs@aAX02yw9PxxgRZ0DLOsXLpfa384wwJOi6SxAXssnlImpMk5ErTOBlMp6mMD3jgA3BHS1bYUpZkW@Ywj6P7MnZMDJ6YjfWScMIFkbUwTMCSB3Aa9wkP0PJyTG3rOHJTNESWEdrN8slYsp0HzpYVfWYEcdMFx/qoJDURiv@h/6uU6doc9vXV5XOFQ2eFwWBX4@bcWItyCn1aEfjSKPYpzDrTaaO41Mkq0oe@32nb3iY9n@uWzbRuTc80DiuH1v3SAZl7YG4ECZbZ7pWuJSq3MdsGwMzdD867fPTC0CxBAbgyEi7aYc5es4gKQrWtZIef5BCNq3A4dW2h5CPuivuDffFvOCru5mQ3RmrRGARapnxeW0zDCdhjsuOljAeFadf1MFDRJA4dHzpOlofJxUBbRX/iGPPEJJdA4jpdHlxxTpzB7Bi83Q4Q3YsFk30HSmjMD@8GIy@izlfGWoouzTs6OuDdRBgFVUE/b25AeCW1XOkEHbss2/5y15ejtBJbjDIELQNPUHb@9JDkD9oP8zr1w208reEC0htjg2qTdI60fyzwHjyD5EIn7OULI1Z6U6x37JsoeupFo8gXxKyrStQdrarvlxBZK0VND0iN3LQJTSJxer//Aw)):

```
1.35 seconds merge_sort
0.91 seconds merge_sort_recursive
0.90 seconds merge_sort_Kelly

1.25 seconds merge_sort
1.05 seconds merge_sort_recursive
0.92 seconds merge_sort_Kelly

1.34 seconds merge_sort
0.81 seconds merge_sort_recursive
0.88 seconds merge_sort_Kelly
```

It's pretty much as fast and I'd say almost as simple as the recursive one. Even the boundary check for `end` was unnecessary after all, as Python slicing handles that for me. The imbalance issue remains.

About memory-efficiency: Actually your iterative one takes *more* memory than your recursive one, not less. Here are allocation peaks during sorting of `list(range(2**17))` as measured with `tracemalloc` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVbLjtowFN3nKyzNYmIITKGLthH0B/oJURSlxAGD85BtWtHRfDv1tR07DulIs2s2kHvPPfd1bOhv8tS1n7/2/H6vSI0awo@kEB2Xcck5TiOkHlojRlptQLs92hgrPJzIK2@R8kTadrhyTlpZCPqHIIXUxt8nykjo2jlCz8VILVXMJ2cwcdrs8atRdngaWqkgDVqGOVY2vauVHk@QoKFtHNuA7WIaghMU@1wYh8lgOlWhfMADL4DLNFmqS1miTZ7APDL7puwmMXhCtrrjiCLaIl62iglYEg/GYZ/wAC3Nh9S6joyqoiEyD9BPqCJsBAucdtAzM1tsHXCyyeB1gQxuvP1QPAUnKkLQX@SjMhrv1GJfXmw@Wzi0nSqMaXlYq515mo@hsxWBDwexszDtxONGzcZHe8IPff8gjN1GPZ9KVk8OgjbNHQDQA7TuFAHIxAETpVawTIQhZMmNrCslBQBM3F1vvctHLwxNE6SAywNVGzvM2QnaoLyKdSuL/XtyCMaVWpy4Mig5M7ui7tSf3TczKmrnpDeGyrZSCGMZ8zlt1RKOx84ky855OCiTdl32PWmr2KLDE0nRcj@6NQgT5D2OIU9IcvYkttPl3hZnxenNlsHZ9QCNe15a2/9SW23s9eVJZ@5OXX5ieBOgTTTJhxT1L4509jrQinUyM41snNi8lJz5osy6sVUw2TP6rrQZCI6CyYwIpDmoQc3fXNTpw1G75LYymk90t3pfdy54SDJRXBB@Ma8RbXqlGyR5eSBNyVh3QKVAsolq3jUgg0p9WJA4XeuakSgCoRReJls7VvOTx6iQsXUsFpsvdsVPQ7heezToDVQLTF7DyexNmzyo/NGy9fM4dP1t@BXwc5DNWq8ixlOg/jMD372n57SVcf38qqKORBZ6RFXRkKbjtxhnmzz9lryhnzdJBEKvwLAuirZsSFG8PeMwadePcpZCENW1SW1yk8qPxSTG9/tf)):

```
3,342,704 bytes  merge_sort
2,892,479 bytes  merge_sort_recursive
2,752,720 bytes  merge_sort_Kelly
  525,572 bytes  merge_sort_Kelly2 (see text below)
```

The peaks are reached during the final / top-level merge. Your iterative one takes more because when computing the final `merged_arr`, that variable still holds the previous one. Can be avoided with `del merged_arr` when it's no longer needed. Then it only takes 2,752,832 bytes. And of course all our solutions could take less memory if we didn't make so many slice copies but rather worked with indexes instead. That's what `merge_sort_Kelly2` does. It only copies in its merge function, and only copies one half out and then merges that half and the other half in the original list into the original list.

**end of update, original answer:**

> Why would you ever use recursive over iterative

Mainly because it's simpler/nicer. For example, your recursive one can sort `[3, 1, 4]` while your iterative one crashes with an `IndexError`. No doubt because it's more complicated.

The recursive one is also more balanced, needing fewer comparisons. Left and right are always equally large or differ by just one element.  For example, for `arr = list(range(2**17))`, both do 1114112 comparisons, because both are equally perfectly balanced. But with `2**17+1`, the iterative one does 1245184 comparisons while the recursive one only does 1114113. Because the iterative one at the end merges 2^17 elements with 1 element (and that one element happens to be the largest).

> I timed these two implementations and found iterative does in fact appear to be faster.

I get the opposite. Even for 2^17 elements, so that the iterative one doesn't have the imbalance issue. Times for sorting three lists both ways:

```
1.23 seconds merge_sort
0.83 seconds merge_sort_recursive

1.25 seconds merge_sort
0.82 seconds merge_sort_recursive

1.19 seconds merge_sort
0.80 seconds merge_sort_recursive
```

Code:

```
from random import shuffle
from time import time

for _ in range(3):
    arr = list(range(2**17))
    shuffle(arr)
    for sort in merge_sort, merge_sort_recursive:
        copy = arr[:]
        t0 = time()
        copy = sort(copy)
        print(f'{time()-t0:.2f} seconds {sort.__name__}')
        assert copy == sorted(arr)
    print()
```

Comment: Sorry my implementation wasn't working. But I don't get why you are trying to be rude. I am just wondering the tradeoffs. You can use any actual working versions of the algorithms and my question still applies.

Comment: Rude? What are you talking about?

Comment: I mean picking at my programming error isn't exactly answering what my question was focused on but thats fine. Your point that it is a preference/style based decision has been made. I figured as much but was wondering if there was more to it that I did not understand.

Comment: @ventrejo I said it's ***simpler*** (also making it nicer for reading/understanding). That's not at all about "preference/style". And then I provided evidence for the simplicity difference by pointing put an error to illustrate that the more complicated code is also more error-prone. That has nothing to do with being rude. And after your fix it might be correct now, but it would take me a lot more time and brain-power to verify that, as it's more complicated than the simpler recursive one.

Comment: @ventrejo I added another reason now, but the simplicity remains my main reason.

Comment: Bund That makes sense sorry.  I just don't think recursively very well so it doesn't exactly feel simpler to me. I am sure to someone more experienced the recursive approach may be objectively simpler. I just think of style choice kind of think of style as being influenced by what a person finds simpler. Although I know there are other factors such as style inherent to a language.

Comment: @ventrejo Hmm, ok, if you're not as used to recursion itself, I can understand it might not be simple to you. Although I don't really remember what that was like for me, I've been used to it for so many years :-). But besides familiarity with recursion, I'd say the recursive one is objectively simpler. Your iterative one has *additional* code to deal with the boundary and to subtract indices that the recursive one doesn't have. And it's not just yours, the one on Wikipedia also has such additional boundary handling and I guess that's inherent.

Comment: It's not true that the recursive merge sort is "more balanced" than iterative. If the iterative sort is written competently then the segments it sorts are exactly the same or differ only by one, and it makes the same number of comparisons that the recursive version makes. I'm not saying that the iterative version is faster (I haven't timed it) or better (which would be only opinion), but that it doesn't suffer from the imbalance that you attribute to it.

Comment: @ventrejo Added a benchmark now, the recursive one is *faster* for me. Could you share your benchmark code and results as well?

Comment: @JimMischel I'm sure you *can* write an iterative one that uses the exact same segments (after all, you can simulate the recursive one iteratively). But neither the OP's does, nor Wikipedia's does, nor Python's does (timsort does try to avoid really bad imbalances by using a good minimum run length, but even if there are no natural runs longer than that so that all but the last run have that length, it's not as perfectly balanced as the simple recursive one). Can you show such a "competent" iterative one?

Comment: @KellyBundy Emulating the recursive one iteratively isn't what I had in mind. It's possible I mis-read some code? I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: @JimMischel Yeah I just meant that as an extreme to show it's possible. I'm curious about an actual one. I don't think I've seen an iterative mergesort that attempts perfect balance, have only seen powers-of-2 and what timsort does.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy Well that is embarrassing, I had an extra digit in the list i was using for the recursive benchmark. Honestly I was wondering why they were so dramatically different which was the entire reason I sparked this question. The actual results are in line with yours. But I kind of assume this is more because my implementation of the iterative algorithm is flawed. And not because the most efficient recursive version is actually faster than the most efficient iterative one?

Comment: @ventrejo I guess "extra digit" means ten times more elements? And yeah, your particular implementation is at least partially to "blame", could certainly be improved. For starters, I'd replace the for-loop with a slice assignment. But I don't know which one would win if both were done most efficiently.

Comment: @ImNewAndLearning Note the new update section with my own simpler iterative version.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks I appreciate you providing me with a better example than my own. This stuff is a little beyond my skill level, but are you sure about the memory being worse in the iterative one? https://perfpy.com/215 the peak memory according to this benchmark seems much higher in the recursive. Not sure how reliable the site is for benchmarking I guess though.

Comment: @ImNewAndLearning Yes, I'm sure. I don't know what that site does. It's very inconsistent. I ran that multiple times and for the iterative one, it once reported <1 KB, then 8 KB, then 52 KB, then <1 KB. Rubbish. Especially the <1 KB, it definitely takes more than that (for your 998 elements).